# Change material on multiple (different) objects simultaneously

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, linked-data

Is there a way to "link" two different object's materials, so that if I choose a different material on one it changes on the other, without technically "joining" the objects?  Not talking about changing the nodes inside a material, I mean substituting an entirely different material to the current slot.

I am modeling a rifle and I have 2 parts that I want to always share the same material.  Using Cycles.

Comment: just assign the same material to both.

Comment: I know how to do that.  I want to create several skins for the rifle, and I don't want to have to manually switch to a different material on both objects every time I want to change it.  (2 objects isn't a lot, but future projects might have more objects in this kind of situation)  Just assigning the same material to both doesn't exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly, no. But there a few workarounds.

### Object Groups

You can quickly copy the materials from the active object to all selected objects with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Materials*.

Combining that with groups, you can "store" selections of objects for later. Group the selected objects together with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, then update the materials of the group by activating the object with the updated materials and pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (to reselect the group) then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Materials*.

### Node Groups

I know you specifically asked about switching materials and not about altering a single material. However, if you relax that constraint a bit you can use [node groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/groups.html) to achieve this. Put the entirety of your material in a node group (<kbd>A</kbd> to select all nodes, then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>), and voila:

[image]

Note that in this example, the objects have separate materials: "Material A" and "Material B". They could instead share the same material, or have multiple materials each, some shared and some not. The link is through the node group.

Comment: The method of using groups will do.  Thanks!